# Series summation of polynomial on x multiplied by x power summation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, power-series

An unbiased coin is tossed repeatedly and outcomes are recorded. What is the expected no of toss to get HT ( one head and one tail consecutively) ?

I tried to solve above question using the following probability tree diagram.

[image]

Probability in each branch is = $0.5$. I double circled the satisfying toss events.
While observing the diagram I noticed that, from 2nd toss onward our required event starts showing up. Additionally,

1. in the $\text{2nd}$ toss (or the 3rd level) we have one satisfying case.
2. in the $\text{3rd}$ toss (or the 4th level) we have two satisfying case.
3. in the $\text{4th}$ toss (or the 5th level) we have three satisfying case.
4. in the $\text{5th}$ toss (or the 6th level) we have four satisfying case.
5. etc.

i.e. in the $\text{kth}$ toss we would have $(k-1)$ satisfying case.
So,

$\\ E = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty } k.P(k)\
\\ E = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty } k.\left \{ (k-1)*(0.5)^k \right \}\\
\\ E = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty } \left \{ (k^2-k)*(0.5)^k \right \}\\$

I understand the series summation would converge because we have the $0.5^{k}$ term which eventually becomes zero.

But could not solve this polynomial and power series summation.

Please suggest how to solve this and or any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can describe  all valid  tosses  as follows:

> The valid tosses are
>
> - zero or more tosses of T followed by
> - zero or more tossed of H followed by
> - HT
>
> This corresponds to the tree diagram where we can see following valid paths starting from the root
>
> \begin{array}{lllllllllll}
> &HT\qquad&H^2T\qquad&H^3T\qquad&\color{blue}{H^4T}\qquad&H^5T\qquad&\cdots\\
> &THT&TH^2T&\color{blue}{TH^3T}&TH^4T&TH^5T&\cdots\\
> &T^2HT&\color{blue}{T^2H^2T}&T^2H^3T&T^2H^4T&T^2H^5T&\cdots\\
> &\color{blue}{T^3HT}&T^3H^2T&T^3H^3T&T^3H^4T&T^3H^5T&\cdots\\
> &T^4HT&T^4H^2T&T^4H^3T&T^4H^4T&T^4H^5T&\cdots\\
> &\quad\vdots&\quad\vdots&\quad\vdots&\quad\vdots&\quad\vdots&\\
> \end{array}
>
> Note the entries in a diagonal have the same length, starting with the first node $HT$ of length $2$. The entries in the diagonal with length $5$ are marked in blue.

From this scheme we can derive the expectation value. We obtain following the same arrangement

\begin{align*}
E[X]=\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n p_n&=2p(HT)+3p(H^2T)+4p(H^3T)+\color{blue}{5p(H^4T)}+\cdots\\
&\qquad+3p(THT)+4p(TH^2T)+\color{blue}{5p(TH^3T)}+6p(TH^4T)+\cdots\\
&\qquad+4p(T^2HT)+\color{blue}{5p(T^2H^2T)}+6p(T^2H^3T)+7p(T^2H^4T)+\cdots\\
&\qquad+\color{blue}{5p(T^3HT)}+6p(T^3H^2T)+7p(T^3H^3T)+8p(T^3H^4T)+\cdots\\
&\qquad+\cdots\\
\end{align*}

We can add up these values along the diagonals. Note, the diagonal marked in blue has $4$ entries

$$\{HHHHT,THHHT,TTHHT,TTTHT\}$$
of length $5$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> E[X]&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\\
> &=\left.\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)x^{n+1}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=x^2\left.\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)x^{n-1}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=x^2\left.\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)nx^{n-2}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=\left.\left(x^2D_x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=\left.\left(x^2D_x^2\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=\left.\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &=4
> \end{align*}

Here we use the differential operator $D_x:=\frac{d}{dx}$ and apply it to the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.

Comment: The wiki link directly points me the exact required formula. Thanks.

Comment: @Debashish: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can treat this as a [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) with the following states:

End, Head, Tail (not end)  (*or equivalently worded, HT has occured, heads is most recent result, and no heads have occured respectively*)

This has the transition matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0.5&0\\0&0.5&0.5\\0&0&0.5\end{bmatrix}$, which is in the standard form for an absorbing chain: $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S\\\hline0&R\end{array}\right]$

We look to the [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix): $(I-R)^{-1}$ which in this case is $\begin{bmatrix}0.5&-0.5\\0&0.5\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{1/4}\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0&0.5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$

The fundamental matrix holds the information about how many steps are expected until we reach an absorbing state.  Since our initial state can be thought of as being a tail (*or more correctly worded, as being that no head has yet occurred*), we look to the corresponding column and add the entries to find the expected time.

In this case, we see it will take an expected number of $2+2=4$ flips to have flipped a tails after a heads.

Comment: Thanks ! please suggest or give some good reference regarding this Markov Chain Method.

Comment: The wikipedia links I already included have a good bit of information in them.  Otherwise, [PatrickJMT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvYTGEZQTEs) covers the basics rather well, though his notation differs from mine and textbooks from which I've taught and studied from in the past in that he uses row-stochastic matrices instead of column-stochastic matrices, so his state vectors will appear on the left and have rows summing to one, whereas I would write it with column vectors on the right of matrix with columns summing to one.  He begins discussing absorbing chains in part 7 of his videos.